# How does hyperelliptic involution act on the standard generators of the fundamental group of surfaces of genus g with n punctures?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, riemann-surfaces, mapping-class-groups, fundamental-group

Let $S_{g,n}$ be the surface of genus $g$ with $n$ punctures. We know that $\pi_1(S_{g,n})$ admits a presentation:

$$\left\langle~ \alpha_1,\beta_1,\dots, \alpha_{g},\beta_{g},\gamma_{1},\dots,\gamma_{n}~\middle|~\prod_{i = 1}^{n} \gamma_{i}\prod_{i = 1}^{g} [\alpha_{i},\beta_{i}]~\right\rangle.$$
Let $J$ be a hyperelliptic involution on $S_{g,n}$ as depicted in the figure below:

[image]

i.e. $J$ fixes $r\leq2g+2$ punctures and permutes $n-r$ punctures. Then $J$ will induce an automorphism $J_*$ of $\pi_1(S_{g,n})$ unique up to $\mathrm{Inn}(\pi_1(S_{g,n}))$. Then I have the following questions:

Q1. What is a smart choice(in the sense of Q2) of loops and base-point in the figure above satisfying the above-mentioned presentation?

Q2. How to compute $J_*(\alpha_i)$, $J_*(\beta_i)$, and $J_*(\gamma_j)$ in terms of $\alpha_i, \beta_i, \gamma_j$ for that choice?

Comment: A fundamental group is defined relative to a basepoint.  Where is the basepoint in your presentation?

Comment: @MikhailKatz: since the question says “unique up to [inner automorphisms]”, the choice of base point doesn’t matter.

Comment: It certainly does matter, since the action of the involution on the elements of the fundamental group cannot even be defined if you don't deal with the issue of the fixed point.

Comment: @MikhailKatz: different choices of base point lead to automorphisms that differ by an inner automorphism. This is proved in the first few lectures of any undergraduate course in algebraic topology.

Comment: @HJRW, what you say is correct *once the action is defined*.  Before making sure the action is well-defined, it is not clear to me that the question is meaningful at all.  Believe me, I have several publications on hyperelliptic surfaces.

Comment: @MikhailKatz: I suggest you look at Farb and Margalit’s *Primer*, especially the section on the Dehn—Nielsen—Baer theorem. This is all quite standard.

Comment: @MikhailKatz - you are correct that the hyperelliptic involution $J$ does not act on the fundamental group - this is because it does not fix any points, so cannot fix a base-point.  However, the *mapping class* of $J$ gives an *outer automorphism* of the fundamental group (say with basepoint in front of the dotted line, halfway in-between the first two "x"s).  As HJRW points out, this is the content of the (easy direction) of the Dehn-Nielsen-Baer theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_class_group_of_a_surface#The_Dehn%E2%80%93Nielsen%E2%80%93Baer_theorem

Comment: @Sam, I am not sure what you mean when you say that the hyperelliptic involution does not fix any points.  The number of fixed points of the hyperelliptic involution is easily determined by the Riemann-Roch theorem.  For example, for the torus one gets 4, and for the genus-2 surface one gets 6.  Besides, the fixed points are clearly indicated by x's in the OP's picture (some of them are deleted as punctures).

Comment: @HJRW, one doesn't need the Dehn-Nielsen-Baer theorem since one can just choose a fixed point of $J$ to be the basepoint, but the OP didn't even say that.  The main problem with the question is that the one-relator presentation is merely an abstract presentation of the fundamental group, and is not directly related to the figure he drew.  Since the generating loops are not specified, the question is not really well-posed.

Comment: @MikhailKatz: There seem to be several points of confusion here. Most of all, it's a real shame that you have chosen to hassle a new poster who asked a perfectly well-posed question. Regarding the maths: First, the crosses in the question indicate punctures rather than marked points (note that the given presenttion presents a free group), so there are no fixed points. Second, the Dehn--Nielsen--Baer theorem  *does* resolve the ambiguity you now you say you worry about -- which seems to be different from your initial criticism, because it does not just involve base points...

Comment: (cont'd) ... The DNB theorem (specificlly the version for surfaces with punctures) implies that any two ways of presenting the fundamental group like that differ taken by a mapping class. Therefore, the resulting formula for the action of the hyperelliptic involution is well defined up to conjugation.

Comment: @HJRW - thank you for explaining!

Comment: @MikhailKatz - I should have reiterated that the question is only interesting *because* all of the fixed-points of $J$ have been punctured away. Your concern about the presentation is, I think, misplaced.  Choose *any* base point and ask yourself how $J$ “acts” on it…

Comment: I would be happy to discuss this further, but the comments thread is not my preferred place for that. If you like, we can open a chat room?

Comment: @HJRW: thanks for the clarification. You refer to "the resulting formula for the action of the hyperelliptic involution", apparently relative the the presentation mentioned in the *question*.  Are you implying that you have one?

Comment: @SamNead: thanks for your comments.  I have a similar question as above.

Comment: @MikhailKatz - I've already shown how to do this, for $S_{0, 4}$, in my answer below. I can draw the picture I think you want for $S_{1, 4}$ (and for $S_{g, 2g + 2}$ generally)... but not in the comments thread!  I suggest you ask your question as a separate post on MO (giving a link back to this post).

Comment: @MikhailKatz: Sorry for the very slow reply. I don’t have such a formula, but producing one is, as Sam Nead indicates, a well-posed exercise. (Contrary to your comments, which suggested that it isn’t well-posed.)

Answer (score 3):

Below is a cartoon showing one "solution" for $S_{0, 4}$.  I'd encourage you to think about $S_{0, 6}$ next, then deal with $S_{1,4}$, then deal with $S_{2, 6}$, and then ponder the general case.  Note that there is never a unique solution; this is because one must make a choice of a point-pushing map to "restore" the basepoint.

[image: Cartoon showing the action of J (and a point push) on the generators of the fundamental group]